# Error al utilizar metodo PUT en react usando una FAKE API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend

estoy utilizando una fake API para hacer un e-commerse en react, y me
tope con un problema que no estoy pudiendo solucionar. Al momento de
querer ejecutar el metodo PUT para modificar un producto que esta en
la base de datos, me borra todo el contenido del mismo, no me lo
actualiza. Este problema no lo tengo con el metodo DELETE, ya que al ejecutarlo cumple la funcion y elimina el producto de la base de datos y por lo tanto de la lista donde es mostrado. el codigo del componente donde lo implemento es el
siguiente

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ListProducts from "./ListProducts";
import NavBar from "../navBar/NavBar";
import Footer from "../footer/Footer";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../services/themeContext/Theme.context";

const ProductContainer = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState(null);

  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Llama a la API aquí
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/products", {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setProducts(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
  }, []);

  const deleteProductHandler = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/products/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          alert("Producto eliminado con exito");
          setProducts((prevProducts) =>
            prevProducts.filter((product) => product.id !== id)
          );
          // const newListProducts = products.filter(
          //   (product) => product.id !== id
          // );
          // setProducts(newListProducts);
        } else {
          throw new Error("No se pudo eliminar el producto.");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  const editProductHandler = (product) => {
    setSelectedProduct(product);
  };
  const cancelFormHandler = () => {
    setSelectedProduct(null);
  };

  const updateProductHandler = () => {
    if (!selectedProduct) return;

    // Llamada a la API para actualizar el producto seleccionado
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/products/${selectedProduct.id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      // headers: {
      //   "Content-Type": "application/json",
      // },
      body: JSON.stringify(selectedProduct),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Error al actualizar el producto");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((updatedProduct) => {
        // Actualizar la lista de productos con el producto actualizado
        setProducts((prevProducts) =>
          prevProducts.map((product) =>
            product.id === updatedProduct.id ? updatedProduct : product
          )
        );
        // Limpiar la selección después de la actualización
        setSelectedProduct(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error("Error", err));
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${theme === "DARK" && "dark-theme"}`}>
      <NavBar />
      <div>
        <ListProducts
          products={products}
          deleteProductHandler={deleteProductHandler}
          editProductHandler={editProductHandler}
        />
        <div className="row justify-content-center mt-5 p-5">
          {selectedProduct && (
            <form className="border rounded-3 col-6 p-5 mt-5">
              <h2>Ingreso de un producto</h2>
              <div className="input-container mt-3 mb-4">
                <label>Ingrese el nombre del producto:</label>
                <input
                  className={`${
                    theme === "DARK"
                      ? "form-control form-control-lg bg-dark text-light"
                      : "form-control form-control-lg bg-light text-dark"
                  }`}
                  placeholder={`${selectedProduct.name}`}
                  type="text"
                  value={selectedProduct.name}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const inputValue = e.target.value;
                    if (inputValue.length <= 0) {
                      alert("Ingrese un nombre correcto");
                    } else {
                      setSelectedProduct({
                        ...selectedProduct,
                        name: inputValue,
                      });
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-container mt-3 mb-4">
                <label>Tipo de producto a modificar:</label>
                <input
                  className={`${
                    theme === "DARK"
                      ? "form-control form-control-lg bg-dark text-light"
                      : "form-control form-control-lg bg-light text-dark"
                  }`}
                  disabled
                  placeholder={`${selectedProduct.type}`}
                  value={selectedProduct.type}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-container mt-3 mb-4">
                <label>Ingrese el precio del producto:</label>
                <input
                  className={`${
                    theme === "DARK"
                      ? "form-control form-control-lg bg-dark text-light"
                      : "form-control form-control-lg bg-light text-dark"
                  }`}
                  min="0"
                  placeholder={`${selectedProduct.price}`}
                  type="number"
                  value={selectedProduct.price}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const inputValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
                    if (inputValue <= 0) {
                      alert("Ingrese un precio correcto");
                    } else {
                      setSelectedProduct({
                        ...selectedProduct,
                        price: inputValue,
                      });
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              {/* <div className="text-danger">{error}</div> */}
              <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-outline-secondary col-4"
                  onClick={() => {
                    updateProductHandler(selectedProduct);
                  }}>
                
                  Modificar producto
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-outline-danger col-4"
                  onClick={cancelFormHandler}
                >
                  Cancelar
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductContainer;
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias!